# How can remove an attribute from a React component?

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to modify this section of code.

```
const DisplayTheSecret = props => (
  <div>
    <span aria-hidden="true">
    The secret to life is {props.secretToLife}.
    </span>
  </div>
);
```

How can I remove the attribute `aria-hidden` from it?

### HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

### JS file

```
const DisplayTheSecret = props => (
  <div>
    <span  aria-hidden="true">
    The secret to life is {props.secretToLife}.
    </span>
  </div>
);

const withSecretToLife = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...this.props}
          secretToLife={42}
          // like to remove aria-hidden or set it to aria-hidden="false"
        />
      );
    }
  }
        
  return HOC;
};


const Life = withSecretToLife(DisplayTheSecret);


ReactDOM.render(<Life />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Comment: when do you want to change the `area-hidden` attribute?

Comment: when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vanilla [`.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

like this:

```
<span id="your-id" aria-hidden="true">
    The secret to life is {props.secretToLife}.
</span>
```

```
document.getElementById("your-id").removeAttribute("aria-hidden");
```